# How to use DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync to Enumerate all BLE devices visible to Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, bluetooth, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

1. I have a code to list all the BluetoothLE devices a Windows Phone 8.1 can detects (paired and unpaired):

   ```
       var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync( BluetoothLEDevice.GetDeviceSelector() );
       foreach ( DeviceInformation di in devices )
           {
           BluetoothLEDevice bleDevice = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync( di.Id );

           Debug.WriteLine( bleDevice.Name );
           }
   ```

However, the line:

```
var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync( BluetoothLEDevice.GetDeviceSelector() );
```

Throws an exception.

**Any Idea why?**

2. I also tried this code:

   var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync( GattDeviceService.GetDeviceSelectorFromUuid( GattServiceUuids.GenericAttribute ) );

This code doesn't throw an exception, but returns 0 devices.

**Any Idea why?**

In both case, the DeviceCapability is defined as follows:

```
    <m2:DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth.genericAttributeProfile">
        <m2:Device Id="any">
            <m2:Function Type="name:genericAttribute"/>
        </m2:Device>
    </m2:DeviceCapability>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are working with Windows Phone 8.1 you are not able to enumerate the non paired devices. This changes with Windows 10 SDK release 1511

Comment: Hi Dan. Thanks for your quick answer :)
I will need besides discovering the BLE devices to custom BOND (vs. regular Pairing) with the device. Not sure how achieve that without even being able to discover which BLE devices are around.